# What's the database.yml configuration for using Rails with RethinkDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rethinkdb, nobrainer

I am trying to dive into RethinkDB with Rails and followed the steps until here: https://rethinkdb.com/docs/rails/

How do I configure the database adapter for RethinkDB though?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation I read:

> We'll be using NoBrainer—a RethinkDB ORM, which is an almost drop-in replacement for ActiveRecord.

This implies you will replace ActiveRecord, hence the configuration will not happen in database.yml which, instead, is the ActiveRecord configuration file.

Check the [NoBrainer](http://nobrainer.io/) docs to understand how the database is configured. Specifically, [this page](http://nobrainer.io/docs/installation/) tells you how to configure it. There is a specific setting called

```
config.rethinkdb_urls = [config.default_rethinkdb_url]
```

where you specify the database connection string.